# How disable handling mouse events on content area in jfxtras window?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, jfxtras

I can drag jfxtras `Window` by clicking on `ImageView` in window area. I need to handle mouse move, swipe... events by `ImageView`. How disable handling mouse events on content window area?

Note: You can drag window by `ImageView` in content area, but can't by `Button`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. But it seems like hack:

```
imageView.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {                    
        window.setMovable(false)
    }
});
imageView.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        window.setMovable(true);
    }
});
```